# Verification of SQL to Report on All Children of a Given Parent in Simple Oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I'm hoping this is a pretty simple request... I'm not a developer or DBA, but I have dabbled in with Perl, PHP and PowerShell.  Anyway, we have a table of about 400 Parents and Children.  A snippet of the table is at the bottom of this post.  I can provide the whole list of 412 parent/children if the complete depth is required.

The SOURCE_ID and DESTINATION_ID are representing web services in a SOA environment.  For this exercise, we just need to pick one of the services, then display the "downstream" children beneath it in the hierarchy.  Also, we'd like to know the "upstream" parents all the way up the hierarchy as well.

I originally just cut and pasted the table into a text file and used this [PERL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862217/create-a-hierarchy-file-using-perl) to produce a hierarchy file which I then pasted into excel.  Long story short, **I came up with 25 unique ID's** which I assumed were all children of the SOURCE_ID.

I want to do this with a SQL query so I can make an interactive/self-serve web page and not have a manual process to worry about.  I found and manipulated this code from somewhere on this site:

```
select Source_Service_Id parent, Destination_Service_Id child
from dd_service_relationship
connect by prior id = Source_Service_Id
start with Source_Service_Id = 10512
```

**It only returns 12 results**.  Now I don't know which results to trust.

Please verify that the SQL code should return ALL of the children (with no duplication if the child is under multiple parents), and that it will traverse the entire table.

Here is a small portion of the dd_service_relationship table:

```
ID            UPDATE_DATE                  SOURCE_ID        DESTINATION_ID
10502    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10501                    10500
10504    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10501                    10503
10506    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10501                    10505
10509    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10508                    10507
10511    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10508                    10510
10513    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10508                    10512
10515    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10508                    10514
10517    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10508                    10516
10519    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10508                    10518
10521    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10508                    10520
10523    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10508                    10522
10526    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10525                    10524
10527    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10525                    10505
10529    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10525                    10528
10531    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10525                    10530
10533    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10532                    10505
10534    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10532                    10507
10535    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10532                    10510
10536    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10532                    10512
10538    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10532                    10537
10541    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10540                    10539
10543    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10542                    10514
10544    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10542                    10539
10545    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10542                    10505
10547    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10546                    10518
10549    9/24/2012 2:09:45 PM    10546                    10548
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I ended up piecing together.  Since I'm not a developer, I can't vouch for it's efficiency or proper structure. It does what I had asked for help with, plus it filters by today's date and also pulls the name of the service from another table.  Hope this helps someone else looking for a similar solution:

```
select SERVICE_NAME from DD_SERVICES where ID in (
select distinct DESTINATION_SERVICE_ID from(
    select
    ID,
    SOURCE_SERVICE_ID, 
    DESTINATION_SERVICE_ID, 
    level
    from DD_USER.DD_SERVICE_RELATIONSHIP where trunc(UPDATE_DATE) = trunc(SYSDATE)
    start with SOURCE_SERVICE_ID = {insert root value here}
    connect by prior DESTINATION_SERVICE_ID = SOURCE_SERVICE_ID
    )
)
```